# Minecraft forge server not working / downloading files

Tags: java, server, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've created a bat file with the command line " java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2855.jar nogui " inside my server folder. It keeps closing there is some kind of error.

[image: Error Report from Windows PowerShell]

I removed my name of course from the folders and I blurred out the folder name it's a stupid name.

[image] and that's my folder.

Comment: What's your Java version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appear because of Java version.

The Java that you are using to run this is too different from the one that compile the jar. Such as it's 1.12, it should be below Java 15 if I well remember.

Java 15 is required for spigot & forge 1.13, and Java 16 is required for spigot & forge 1.17.

So, to fix this, you have to change the Java version AND the java environment variable.

Comment: Minecraft 1.12 needs Java 8.